# Master is not ready HBase

Tags: hbase

I'm using HBase on standalone mode.

And I got this error when acceed to localhost:60010 :

> HTTP ERROR 503 Problem accessing /master-status. Reason: Master not ready

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Can you post the logs from your HBase master? Possibly under /var/log/hbase/

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs. 
If you don't find anything relevant (i.e. no errors and no shutdwon) it may be waiting for some resource (I did notice this while it was waiting for HDFS safemode, but since you're in standalone mode that's not the case).

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the host name (from `localhost` to `master`)? if you did try to access to `master:60010`
if you did not just force  the namenode to leave the safemode by the following commannd:

`bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`